# IAM Policy for AWS EC2 start/stop instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I want a user to be able to login to an aws account and start and stop ONE specific ec2-instance.
So far I found out that ec2 describe only works with a catch -all star "*" in the resources.
The user can login, sees all the instances BUT he can't start or stop the instance because a permission denied error shows up :(

This is my policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:Describe*"
],
"Resource": "*"
},
{
"Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"ec2:TerminateInstances",
"ec2:StopInstances",
"ec2:StartInstances"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-central-1a:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:instance/MY_INSTANCE_ID"
}
]
}
```

Comment: I originally started out reading this entry, still can't figure out whats wrong with it https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2KPWZJJ4S26H6/Demystifying-EC2-Resource-Level-Permissions

Then there is a nice tool, but it seems that as soon as i restrict the resource start/stop doesn't work anymore...
https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is, you can't.

The `ec2:Stopinstances`, `ec2:StartInstances` and `ec2:TerminateInstances` do indeed support resource level permissions, but not for the condition key of instance id. They support the condition keys:

- ec2:AvailabilityZone
- ec2:EbsOptimized
- ec2:InstanceProfile
- ec2:InstanceType
- ec2:PlacementGroup
- ec2:Region
- ec2:ResourceTag/tag-key
- ec2:RootDeviceType
- ec2:Tenancy

This is highlighted in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html). (Search for the API calls on the page)

The only potentially useful condition key is `ec2:ResourceTag/tag-key`. You could add a resource tag on the particular instance and allow the user permission to call these 3 API calls on instances with that tag.

However, unless you had the API calls related to tags denied, there would be nothing to stop the user adding the tag to another instance, and performing the API calls on that instance too. You'd need to establish if denying tagging suits your situation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it's answered your question :)

Comment: i tried to upvote it but i don't have enough reputation

Comment: You don't need to upvote it, you just need to click the tick to mark it as correct :)

Comment: I think this might have been true. It now looks like you can limit this by instance ARN

Answer (score 2):

Let me provide a working example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:RebootInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:222222222222:instance/i-02222222222222ddb",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-south-1:222222222222:security-group/sg-022222222abc"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "my.dev-server.com"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroupRules",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkAcls",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:ModifySecurityGroupRules",
                "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-policy-permission-ec2-tags-vpc/) link also useful in understanding this answer.